Stains on black countertop in bathroom
wondering if anyone has ever fixed a similar problem with an impossible stain on a black countertop. Here is a picture:

https://imgur.com/2D6ve5t
The stain on the left is some of that glade plugin oil that leaked out of a canister, the stain on the right is unknown to me but the shape seems like a electric toothbrush stain. Beyond trying to scrub this out with standard cleaning supplies I've tried the following without success:

CLR liquid

magic eraser sponge

dry poultice powder (from company called miracle something), both with clear wrap on and without.


Any help appreciated!

Oil stain, use alcohol

dishwasher detergent (break up a pod if needed) will remove oil and food stains. But, it looks to me like it's not a stain per-se, that is, there's not something there that shouldn't be, there's something missing; the clear finish on the counter top. Remove all the seal/glaze/lacquer and re-finish if that's the case.

ive used isopropyl alcohol 91% and laundry detergent (tide) without success
